# 2D double for-loop not working

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I want to add the Sales of each day of a month store into a total array file that consists of 3 total Sales. As I need the 3 total sales for comparison.

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern float SalesMonth[3][31]; // the data is in another file
void main()
{
    float average[3], total[3];
    int day, month;
    for ( month = 0; month < 3; month++)
    {
        for ( day = 0; day < 31; day++ )
        {
            total[month] += SalesMonth[month][day];
        }
    printf("%.2f\n", total[month]); // displays crazy digits.
    }
}
```

Link for the result after compiling.
http://snag.gy/aatxd.jpg

Comment: The code above is obviously not complete, because it does not compile. Anyhow - you do not zero the `total` array anywhere.

Comment: `float average[3], total[3],;` is a syntax error. There is a bogus comma. Is this your exact code?

Comment: Instead of "no clue with is wrong", say why you believe something is wrong (giving the compiler error messages if it fails to compile; or examples of incorrect output and the expected output, if it runs but does not behave as expected when run)

Comment: Thanks for pointing those mistakes I've editied them

Answer (score 1):

The last printf will use `month == 3` becaue it just got out of the loop. That's not part of the array you declared so it will read some random bits of the stack.
Try moving the `printf` inside the loop or set the month correctly.

You must also initializae your arrays. Otherwise the values will be something arbitrary.

Also verify that `SalesMonth` actually has the data you expect it to have (you could just print it as you go along).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo

```
float average[3], total[3],;
                          ^^
```

Simply define the arrays the following way

```
float average[3] = { 0.0 }, total[3] = { 0.0 };
```

That is you need to initialize elements of the arrays before using them.

And instead of this statement that does not make sense

```
printf("%.2f\n", total[month]);
```

you must to write a loop that to output each element of the array.

For example

```
for ( month = 0; month < 3; month++) printf("%.2f\n", total[month]);
```

Comment: This happened
Debug Error!
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'total' was corrupted.

Comment: @AgentPerry The code I showed is correct. So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @AgentPerry   You have to place the loop I showed outside the loops where you calculate values of total.